# Problem in Setting Android - Need to ReSet ADT !

Tags: android, sdk, set, adt

I am on Windows 7 with JDK 1.6. I downloaded Android SDK. Added and setup ADT for Eclipse. Wrote a Hello World app in Android. Eclipse is not able to identify "Activity" and other android packages. I added tools folder to path. Still am receiving the same problem.

In Eclipse I started getting message "SDK misssing... Run SDK set up". On reading more, I found that I had to install the SDK prior installing ADT. Now am trying to install SDK, but it says "tools folder is being used by some app". I removed from path also and closed all applications, explorer, etc yet I receive the same message.

I guess the only place left is the setting of ADT in Eclipse. Am I correct ? If so, what to do to install the SDK and then set ADT ! Or what's wrong can anyone point out and help me set Android on my PC.

Any help is highly appreciative.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you set SDK location in eclipse? To set SDK location in Eclipse go to <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, under android set SDK Location path and click apply.

Comment: yes, I have set the SDK in Eclipse and its set properly, but it says "SDK Missing".